# Canard gem - how should I programatically make an admin user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, cancan

I'm using the [Canard gem](https://github.com/james2m/canard) (CanCan + RoleModel) for authentication on Ruby on Rails, but I'm having some issues with making an initial user admin. An Account has Users. When an Account is created, there's an Owner User who has billing details. I'd like that Owner to have the :admin role.

```
class SomewhereElseInSystem
  ...
  account = Account.register(hash) # Company Admin submits form with
                                   # details of account, owning user,
                                   # and a load more objects we don't
                                   # show here.
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy, include: [:profile]
  has_one :owner, class_name: 'User', conditions: { owner: true }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner

  def self.register(details)
    ...
    hash = { name:   details[:client_name],
             domain: details[:subdomain],
             plan:   details[:plan],
             owner_attributes: {
               name:                  details[:owner_name],
               password:              details[:owner_password],
               password_confirmation: details[:owner_password],
               email:                 details[:owner_email] } } 
    account = Account.create hash
    ...
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  acts_as_user roles: [:saas_admin, :admin, :manager]

  # owner is a boolean DB field

  before_validation :owners_are_admins

  protected

  def owners_are_admins
    return unless owner
    self.roles << :admin
  end
end
```

However, I'm finding that when I make an account the associated owner is not an admin, and has no roles set. I've tried several variations on the above and am convinced that I'm missing something basic. Help?

**Update:** 
If I go into the console, I can have great fun seeing 4 non-admins instead of 1 admin and 3 non-admins via the scopes, but a different answer via admin? and the actual fields.

```
[46] subscriptions »  account.users.count
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."account_id" = 1
=> 4
[47] subscriptions »  account.users.admins.count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."account_id" = 1 AND ("users"."roles_mask" & 2 > 0)
[48] subscriptions »  account.users.non_admins.count
[48] subscriptions »  account.users.non_admins.count
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE "users"."account_id" = 1 AND ("users"."roles_mask" & 2 = 0 or "users"."roles_mask" is null)
=> 4
[49] subscriptions »  account.users.map(&:admin?)
=> [
  [0] false,
  [1] false,
  [2] false,
  [3] true
]
[51] subscriptions »  account.users.select{ |user| user.roles_mask & 2 > 0 }.count 0;34# Same as query above
=> 1
```

But better yet, if I do

```
account.users.admins # 0
owner = account.owner
owner.roles << :admin # Should be a no-op
owner.save!
account.user.admins # 1!
```

Clearly my callback isn't doing the equivalent of the << in the console after all. Which I don't understand.

Comment: Can you share the code that you're using to create the account and owner user?

Comment: Updated code above to show "register" calls.